# How to change the caption of Algorithm

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

```
{\tiny
\restylealgo{boxed}
\begin{algorithm}
%\centering{
\SetLine
\KwIn{$A$. }

\caption{}
%}
\label{algo2}
\end{algorithm}
}
```

In the caption it is coming as "Algorithm 2:"
Is it possible just Algorithm 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

{\tiny
\RestyleAlgo{boxed}
\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{}
\begin{algorithm}
%\centering{
%\SetLine
\KwIn{$A$. }

\caption{}
%}
\label{algo2}
\end{algorithm}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: It is `\RestyleAlgo` and not `\restylealgo`, unless you have a very old version of `algorithm2e`.